# Align multiple ggplot2 graphs with a common x axis and different y axes, each with different y-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to get on the same graph, for the same axis x, two axes y
different. One on the right (number of days: datasets on the weather)
and one on the left (number of species).

I have already made a graph showing the precipitation, temperature for
my dataset on the weather. To this, on the y axis on the right, I
would like to add the axis of the number of species. Is it possible?

You can see below my data and my code for a graph :

```
structure(list(SOUNAME = c("BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", 
"BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)"
), year_month = c("2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", 
"2014-06", "2014-06", "2014-06", "2014-06", "2014-07", "2014-07", 
"2014-07", "2014-07"), pre_type = c("NONE", "HEAVY", "LIGHT", 
"MEDIUM", "NONE", "HEAVY", "LIGHT", "MEDIUM", "NONE", "HEAVY", 
"LIGHT", "MEDIUM"), pre_value = c(3, 6, 20, 2, 16, 2, 9, 2, 3, 
3, 22, 3), tem_type = c("V_COLD", "COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM", "V_COLD", 
"COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM", "V_COLD", "COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM"), 
    tem_value = c(0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 24, 6, 0, 0, 23, 8, 0), nb_species = c(NA, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), x = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("SOUNAME", 
"year_month", "pre_type", "pre_value", "tem_type", "tem_value", 
"nb_species", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data = complet_b, aes(x = x, y = pre_value, fill = pre_type), stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:3, labels=unique(complet_b$year_month)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.3) +
  xlab("date") + ylab ("Number of days of precipitation") +
  ggtitle("Precipitation per month") + labs(fill = "Frequency") +
  geom_bar(data=complet_b,aes(x=x+0.4, y=tem_value, fill=tem_type), width=0.3, stat = "identity") +
  xlab("date") + ylab("Number of days of temperature") +
  ggtitle("Temperature per month") + labs(fill = "Frequency")  +
    geom_point( data = complet_b, aes( x= x, y = nb_species), stat = "identity")
```

I add `geom_point` function for the number of species but I do not
know how to add the axis on the right.

Thank you.

Comment: Please reduce this to one specific question. It's too long and involved for this site. Always think "is this a question other people will also have, that someone could provide an authoritative answer to". Cheers.

Comment: There are way too much information that you're trying to plot in the same panel. Considering separate them or use `facet_grid` / `facet_wrap`